# HTML+JS send form data to PHP using POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm really new to all HTML/JS/PHP but I want to create a simple login page thats connected to a database. User provide username&password, once sumbit button is clicked the webpage will change to user's information page.

So far, I have my data set up and my PHP function is working fine (I tested it with POSTMAN)
, however, I cannot get my HTML/JS working. I've been using the xmlhttp method to talk with PHP but failed

So, here is my html code

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>login page</title>
    <style type ="text/css">
    h3{
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    p{
        text-align:center;

    }
    div{
        text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h3>Login Page</h3>

    <form name="login">
        <p>username: <input id="user" type="text" name="username" /></p>
        <p>password: <input id="pass" type="password" name="password" /></p>
        <p><input type="button" value ="Submit" onclick="showUser(document.getElementById('user').value, document.getElementById('pass').value)" /></p>
    </form>

    <br><br>
    <div id="Info"><b>Student Infomation Table</b></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showUser(user, pass) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                     document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","login.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            xmlhttp.send("username="+user+"&password="+pass);
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

`
Here is the PHP

```
<?php

/*
 * Checks the login 
 */


include_once '/include/post_check.php';
// change header
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//check for post
if (checkPOST("username") && checkPOST("password")) {
    $user_pass = $_POST['password'];
    $user_name = $_POST['username'];
    if ($user_pass == "" || $user_name == "") {
        $temp = array("result" => "false", "reason" => "empty fields");
        echo (json_encode($temp));
        die();
    }
} else {
    $temp = array("result" => "false", "reason" => "not enough fields");
    echo (json_encode($temp));
    die();
}

// connect to MySQL
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxx", "xxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    // Print out reason
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

if($user_name == "xxx" && $user_pass =="xxx"){
    // write query (teacher's account)
    $query = "SELECT *
    FROM STUDENT";
}


$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

echo "<table border='2'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Password</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

checkPOST() function

```
<?php

function checkPOST($field){
    return (isset($_POST[$field]));
}

?>
```

Comment: as a beginner to this, you should not start with old things (but it's good to know how it works on the background ofcourse). I'd suggest to move to library like jQuery

Comment: why is the header json?

Comment: Yeah i do have checkPOST() function and it's working fine

Comment: @user3602778 can we see it? And what exactly is not working? It's not redirecting to the PHP page or what?

Comment: @Royal Bg right, when I click the submit button nothing shows, it just stay in the same page

Comment: @user3602778 that's what the code is supposed to do. The ajax request queries the login.php page, but not redirecting. You should write more lines of javascript in order to catch the reponse from login.php and append it to the current page. Your aproach is used to append response without reidrection. If you need to redirect, you don't need any javascript. Just put `action='login.php'` into your form tag, and change the button to `submit`. Oh, now I saw you have lines of appending. But, wasn't they need to be in reversed order?

Comment: @Royal Bg but if the code are working fine my page should shows a table with users info. referring to <div id="Info"><b>Student Infomation Table</b></div>. and for the action='login.php' method, it was actually my very first approach. but i didn't know how to handle data send back from PHP, so i gave up on that one

Comment: @user3602778 yes, it should, could you show us your console response after clicking the button

Comment: Maybe it's because your login.php fails for some reason, you should turn the error reporting on, so maybe the error will be appended instead of the real result

Comment: sry, i dont know how to get the console response. is that the result? the result for the code above is nothing. no effect at all. but for the action='login.php' i will upload it later.

Comment: <table border='2'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Password</th>
</tr><tr><td>1</td><td>rjing</td><td>123</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>user1</td><td>123</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>user3</td><td>123</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>user4</td><td>123</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>user5</td><td>0</td></tr></table>

Comment: If you click F12 (assuming u r using firefox/chrome) there will appear a menu (firebug in firefox) which has a Console tab. Click this tab, enable it (it will say it's disabled for the first time using) and then reload page, enter details, click the button, and it will fill the response there

Comment: also `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the top of your `login.php` in order to see errors

Comment: Your SQL is failing. Also add to above said `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- somehow when posting via form submission, there are results, if the comment above was that (see this one with `table border...`)

Comment: @RoyalBg I saw it, but past that point, I don't know what the OP's expecting. I tested it to a certain extent and got back results. It's up to the OP to elaborate on "what's not working" as well as expected results.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it too, and it's ok, that's why I want to console response :)

Comment: I'm using Chrome yet it worked, but did get this back in my console `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.` @RoyalBg I don't use that type of login system myself, I keep up to date with today's JS methods. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- me neither, tbh it took me some minutes to fully understand the javascript in this post

Comment: I'm wondering if OP's JS is loading at all by being blocked by some type of JS blocker or browser's JS is disabled, if that's what the OP states when saying JS isn't working. @RoyalBg

Comment: @Fred-ii- you might have a point :)

Comment: @RoyalBg Either JS is blocked and/or query is failing. It's black or white and nothing gray in between ;-)

Comment: hi, i was busy doing else. so here is the error in console:"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/wamp/www/project/login.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. " and "Uncaught NetworkError: A network error occurred. " both error refers to html code line 52 which is "xmlhttp.send("username="+user+"&password="+pass);"

Comment: @user3602778 are you opening the HTML/JS from the file system, but not from `localhost/...`

Comment: @RoyalBg That should be rephrased to `You ARE opening the HTML/JS from the file system, but not from localhost/...` ;-)

Comment: @Royal Bg thanks, but after i changed it to http://localhost.. here is new error message "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/project/login.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. "

Comment: i'v added header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *"); and it seem to work :)

Comment: You can answer your own question then, and accept it when SO lets you. @user3602778 with full details also. I will +1 and you get rep points for it too ;-)

Comment: I was searching for what header is needed for this and the OP found it by himself :) it's good to see people are actually debugging their problems

Answer (score 0):

the ERROR is simple one. You missed the method tag and ACTION tag in your form...without method and action tag inside FORM, you cant submit your form data.
so change form tag like this,

<  form name="login"  method="post" action="enter php you want to submit">

Answer (score -1):

use this in html

Name:

use this in php

$name=$_POST ['name'];

```
mysql_connect(your server);
mysql_select_db (your database);
mysql_query (insert into your database);
```